# Extracting a window from an image in each frame

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video

I need to extract a window of size, let's may `m*n`, from an image but the window size varies with each image of frame.  It could be bigger or smaller, and the problem is that I have to add the last frame to the current and only the same size of matrix can add together.

This is what I have tried.  What I did take was I took four possibilities into account, but the results I'm not getting are not satisfactory.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
[f1, f2]=size(hscf);
[f11, f22]=size(Hstcf);

            if( f1> f11  && f2>f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1:f11
        for j=1:1:f22
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
             end
             end
    Hstcf=C;

             elseif(f1<f11 &&f2<f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1:f1
        for j=1:1:f2
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
end
    Hstcf=C;
elseif(f1>f11 && f2<f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1:f11
        for j=1:1:f2
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j)
 end
    end
    Hstcf=C;
elseif(f1<f11 && f2>f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1: f1
        for j=1:1:f22
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
    end
    Hstcf=C;
    elseif(f1<f11 && f2==f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1: f1
        for j=1:1:f22
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
    end
    Hstcf=C;
    elseif(f1>f11 && f2==f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1: f11
        for j=1:1:f22
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
    end
    Hstcf=C;
    elseif(f1==f11 && f2>f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1: f1
        for j=1:1:f22
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
    end
    Hstcf=C;
    elseif(f1==f11 && f2<f22)
    C=zeros(f1,f2);
    for i=1:1: f1
        for j=1:1:f2
            C(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
    end
    Hstcf=C;

end
```

Comment: So what makes the observation window change in size?

Comment: moving target in the frames

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to copy a small image to a large image, starting at the top left corner of the large image. If so, the error is due to following reason. You correctly copy the small image first to an empty matrix called `C`. But after the iteration, you have directly copied modified `C` to your original large image (`Hstcf=C`). Please check the following code snippet.

```
hscf = imread('cameraman.tif');
subplot(1,3,1); imshow(hscf); 
title(strcat(num2str(size(hscf,1)), 'x', num2str(size(hscf,2))));
Hstcf = imresize(imread('coins.png'), .5);
subplot(1,3,2); imshow(Hstcf);
title(strcat(num2str(size(Hstcf,1)), 'x', num2str(size(Hstcf,2))));

[f1, f2]=size(hscf);
[f11, f22]=size(Hstcf);

if (f1>f11 && f2>f22)
    for i=1:f11
        for j=1:f22
            hscf(i,j)=Hstcf(i,j);
        end
    end
end

subplot(1,3,3); imshow(hscf);
title(strcat(num2str(size(hscf,1)), 'x', num2str(size(hscf,2))));
```

Output of this code looks as follows,

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, but this is not what im trying todo, lets say i want to put smaller image into the center of larger image,and i have center points, want to add the smaller image to the center of the bigger image